# How to export with limit and offset using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, offset

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE --compact --where="1 limit 10 offset 20 '" -u root -p mydatabase users > users-10-10.sql
```

I tried the above command and the offset seems not to be working.
it fetches the data from first.

Is there any way to tweak this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Use LIMIT [OFFSET, ] LIMIT 
So some thing like that:

```
mysqldump  db table --where="1 limit 100, 1000" > dump.sql
```

Will select 1000 items skipping 100 first

Comment: It should be noted that the `1` at the start is used to have a WHERE condition that always passes (evaluates to true) given that anything within that `--where` argument simply gets concatenated to the internal backup SQL queries. Other wise you get an invalid query like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LIMIT 100, 100`

Comment: Cool. But will it always be sorted identically, if you execute it multiple times with different limit/offsets?